# how to count the total number of items for the lists contain a specific item in python

Tags: python

I want to get count the total items for the lists contain 'a', which should be 4+3 = 7

```
tweetword = (['a','b','c','a'],['a','e','f'],['d','g'])
count_total_a = {}
for t in tweetword:
    for word in tweetword:
        if word not in count_total_a:
            count_toal_a[word] = len(t)
        if word in count_total_a:
            count_total_a[word] += len(t)
'''the result I get is not correct coz it counts the first list twice'''
```

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the sum over a generator:

```
sum(len(x) for x in tweetword if 'a' in x)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tweetword = (['a','b','c','a'],['a','e','f'],['d','g'])

contains_a = [tweet for tweet in tweetword if 'a' in tweet]

sum_lengths = sum(map(len, contains_a))

print(sum_lengths)
```